# Is a surface locally flat, when the curvature along a line is zero

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curvature

According to Spivak Vol. 2, p. 119 the following holds for a 2-dimensional manifold
$M = \left\{\left(x, y, f(x, y)\right): x, y \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$:
\begin{align*}  
K(x, y, f(x, y)) = \frac{\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}\, \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} - \left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \,\partial y}\right)^2}{\left(1 + \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)^2\right)^2}
\end{align*}
Now, for $f(x, y) = x\cdot y^2 + x^2$ we calculate
\begin{align*}  
K(x, y, f(x, y)) = \frac{4x-4y^2}{\left(1+y^4+4xy^2+4y^2+4x^2y^2\right)^2} = \frac{4(x-y^2)}{\left(1+4y^2+4xy^2+y^4+4x^2y^2\right)^2}
\end{align*}
which is zero for $x = y^2$. Are the following conclusions correct (I set $y=t, t \in \mathbb{R}$):

- The surface around $(t^2, t, f(t^2, t))$ for any $t$ is locally isometric to $\mathbb{R}^2$
- The surface around $(t^2, t, f(t^2, t))$ for any $t$ is flat

Comment: First, you have a typo in the formula for $K$. Second, your denominator for your example looks completely wrong. Third, if a surface is flat along a curve, that does not make it flat in a neighborhood of the curve.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks, mistakes corrected. So my question is, if "flat along a curve" has any meaning / visualization. (I also realized, that the $\Gamma$ symobols vanish in normal coordinates, but not their derivatives. So normal coordinates can't be the reason here.)

Comment: Points where $K=0$ and one principal curvature is nonzero are called parabolic points, and this locus is the parabolic curve. (Points where both principal curvatures are zero are called planar points.) Typical examples are the top/bottom circles on a torus (when you lay it flat on the table) or the bottom of the parabolic trough $z=x^2$. I don't know what you mean by "any meaning."

Comment: @TedShifrin "Flat" suggests to me "look like a plane" (or a zylinder if one principal axis is nonzero).

Comment: @TedShifrin to your other statement: Let e.g. $x=y=0$. Then $f_x(0,0) = f_y(0,0) = 0$ and $f_{xy}(0,0) = 0$ and $f_{xx}(0,0) = 2$ has curvature $2$ but $f_{yy}(0,0) = 0$ has curvature $0$. Thus it looks like a cylinder in $(0,0)$. We have the same situation for all the other points along the curve $(t^2,t,f(t^2,t))$ which you call parabolic points. Right? Is the result for $(t^2,t,f(t^2,t))$ in general obvious? I only see the way to do a lengthy calculation, transforming the coordinates in each point to achieve the axis of main curvature and show that one curvarture is always zero.

Comment: You should download my differential geometry text (free) and read the details on how you do these computations. It's all in Spivak, but that book is definitely more sophisticated. Ultimately, you need the shape operator (derivative of the Gauss map) and its eigenvalues; you get this in matrix form by taking $\text{I}^{-1}\text{II}$ (first and second fundamental forms).

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks a lot. So my overall picture is correct now?

Comment: Yeah. And this computation is not quite so bad. If you are going to have a planar point (rather than a parabolic point), you must have $\text{II}=0$, so all the second-order partials would have to vanish. This never happens, right?

Comment: @TedShifrin Perfect - your book looks nice :-)